Construct a Markov chain satisfying marginal distribution requirements
Given a Markov chain $p(x_{0:T})=p(x_0)\prod_{i=1}^T p(x_i|x_{i-1})$, and a set of functions $C_t(x)$, where $t=0,1,2,\cdots,T$. Can we always construct another Markov chain $q(x_{0:T})=q(x_0)\prod_{i=1}^T q(x_i|x_{i-1})$ such that $q(x_t)\propto p(x_t)C_t(x_t)$ holds for $t=0,1,2,\cdots,T$? Obviously, if $C_t(x)<0$ for some $x$ and $t$, then it is not possible. Thus, we can reasonably limit the consideration of the function class $C_t$ to be: $C_t(x)$ always positive and $\int p(x_t)C_t(x)dx$ is finite.
If we can, prove it. It not, provide a counter example. I think this should be a classical problem that people have investigated in statistics.
